# Login authentication depending on role winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have datatable like this.

```
uid m_code  pass    roleID    
1   F2      F2      2    
2   S2      S2      0
```

And i want to let user log-in depending on their roles.

I tried using this code, but it isn't working at all. Any help much appreciated.

```
        string user = textBox1.Text;
        string pass = textBox2.Text;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from login where m_code='" + user + "' and pass='" + pass + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);


        if(dt.Columns[3].ToString() == "0")
        {
            this.Hide();
            StudentUI s = new StudentUI();
            s.Show();
        }
        if (dt.Columns[3].ToString() == "1")
        {
            this.Hide();
            TeacherUI t = new TeacherUI();
            t.Show();
        }
        if (dt.Columns[3].ToString() == "2")
        {
            FacultyUI f = new FacultyUI();
            f.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
        }
```

Comment: Before addressing the problem itself - you should know that your code poses security risks as it is open to **[Sql Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**

Comment: @Blachshma: Good luck with your SQL injection endeavors on a Winforms app.

Comment: @leppie - Why should it matter if it's a Winforms app? Typing `' or '' ='` in TextBox1 *will* cause an SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Blachshma, you should use parameters to mitigate the risk of Sql Injections.  In the meantime, let's fix up your logic:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
    return;
}

string val = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][3]);

if(val == "0")
{
    this.Hide();
    StudentUI s = new StudentUI();
    s.Show();
}
else if (val == "1")
{
    this.Hide();
    TeacherUI t = new TeacherUI();
    t.Show();
}
else if (val == "2")
{
    FacultyUI f = new FacultyUI();
    f.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You've solved my problem that took around 2 hours :)

Comment: Thanks @Blachsma :) Got a bit distracted when some goose started editing my post.

Comment: And if you don't mind, how can i protect SQL injection? I'm all new to this IT stuff :P

Comment: @TheCatalySt: There's a good example here - http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter